# ExecuteRequestHandler spent most of the time

Tags: performance, iis-7.5, newrelic, azure-cloud-services

I'm working on some performance related tasks and using new relic to diagnose first.
Here is what I have got

[image: New Relic Screenshot]

I'm wondering is it possible to improve on the ExecuteRequestHandler part? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out?

Comment: I am also looking into this,  did you find anything out

Comment: lol not sure, but feels like requests get queued...

Comment: has anyone found out how to see deeper into those segments?

Comment: I'm also facing issue. Has anyone got any resolution ?

Comment: I'm also facing  same issue

Answer (score 0):

**ExecuteRequestHandler** shows your application processing time. To improve this measure is to improve your application logic. It is not a *measure* you can improve on it's own. To improve it you need to improve the code that is actually being executed.

- Increasing resources might reduce this time, but doing that alone without looking at the logic means you have misunderstood the issue or are deliberately ignoring it, if it is an issue at all.

So you need to trace your application logic to determine what is taking so long. New Relic does have a .Net Agent API that you can use to help with this, but without having visibility into what your code is doing New Relic can really only help us to identify endpoint performance and to isolate network and host latencies from the execution of your business logic.

Inside **ExecuteRequestHandler** is your .Net logic, so it makes sense that it would be consuming a large percentage of the overall request processing time. If you are deploying to Azure you should be using Application Insights to monitor and diagnose application logic performance issues inside of **ExecuteRequestHandler**.