# ExecuteRequestHandler of a Cloud service taking too long time (almost 80% of total response time)

Tags: c#, iis-7.5, threadpool, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have a Application (Web API , .NET 4.5) hosted as Azure cloud Service.

Vm size large and 4 instances.

When I am monitoring the application with new relic,I am seeing that  **ExecuteRequestHandler takes almost 80% of total response time** and making the application response very slow.

To increase the performance of the application I want to reduce the time taken by ExecuteRequestHandler.

I tried to search on the internet. but didn't get any help apart from following link.

[ExecuteRequestHandler spent most of the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30489700/executerequesthandler-spent-most-of-the-time)

The above link didn't help much.

Any help on follwoing two points is much appreciated.

1) How to to reduce the time taken by ExecuteRequestHandler

2) How to increase thread pool size of web role.

Comment: Hey, did you figure this out?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum : yes ..with further debuging I found that the query generated by LINQ query was the bittle neck and was taking 90% of the execution time.

Comment: Your response should be marked as answer

Comment: So it was a Linq query inside your method and the time showed up under ExecuteRequestHandler and not something else?